# star rating system (half star)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this rating system on my website and I'm trying to modify it to enable users to give a 'half star' rating for their review of service. What I'm asking is, is it possible with my current code?

My fiddle is below:

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qody1ckz/)

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="rate-ex2-cnt">
    <div id="1" class="rate-btn-1 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="2" class="rate-btn-2 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="3" class="rate-btn-3 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="4" class="rate-btn-4 rate-btn"></div>
    <div id="5" class="rate-btn-5 rate-btn"></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.clear{clear: both;}
.tuto-cnt{width: 480px; background-color: #fff; border:#ccc 1px solid; height:auto; min-height: 400px; margin: 40px auto; padding: 40px; overflow: auto; }

hr{ margin: 10px 0; border:none; border-top: #ccc 1px dotted;}

.rate-ex1-cnt{
    width:225px; height: 40px;
    border:#e9e9e9 1px solid;
    background-color:  #f6f6f6;
}
.rate-ex1-cnt .rate-btn{
    width: 45px; height:40px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../img/rate-btn.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.rate-ex1-cnt .rate-btn:hover, .rate-ex1-cnt  .rate-btn-hover, .rate-ex1-cnt  .rate-btn-active{
    background: url(../img/rate-btn-hover.png) no-repeat;
}

.rate-ex2-cnt{
    width:150px; height: 30px;
    border:#e9e9e9 1px solid;
    background-color:  #f6f6f6;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.rate-ex2-cnt .rate-btn{
    width: 30px; height:30px;
    float: left;
    background: url(http://s18.postimg.org/51iuu62d1/rate_btn2.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.rate-ex2-cnt .rate-btn:hover, .rate-ex2-cnt  .rate-btn-hover, .rate-ex2-cnt  .rate-btn-active{
    background: url(http://s22.postimg.org/l2jhmglml/rate_btn2_hover.png) no-repeat;
}

.rate-ex3-cnt{
    width:85px; height: 17px;
    border:#e9e9e9 1px solid;
    background-color:  #f6f6f6;
}
.rate-ex3-cnt .rate-btn{
    width: 17px; height:17px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../img/rate-btn3.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.rate-ex3-cnt .rate-btn:hover, .rate-ex3-cnt  .rate-btn-hover, .rate-ex3-cnt  .rate-btn-active{
    background: url(../img/rate-btn3-hover.png) no-repeat;
}


/* rate result */
.rate-result-cnt{
    width: 82px; height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: #ccc 0px solid;
}
.rate-result-cnt-all{
    width: 82px; height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: #ccc 0px solid;
}
.rate-stars{
    width: 82px; height: 18px;
    background: url(../img/rate-stars.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
}
.rate-stars-all{
    width: 82px; height: 18px;
    background: url(../img/rate-stars-all.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
}
.rate-bg{
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #ffbe10;
    position: absolute;
}
.rate-bg-all{
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #ffbe10;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){ 
        $('.rate-btn').hover(function(){
            $('.rate-btn').removeClass('rate-btn-hover');
            var therate = $(this).attr('id');
            for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
                $('.rate-btn-'+i).addClass('rate-btn-hover');
            };
        });

        $('.rate-btn').click(function(){    
            var therate = $(this).attr('id');
            var dataRate = 'act=rate&post_id=1&rate='+therate; //
            $('.rate-btn').removeClass('rate-btn-active');
            for (var i = therate; i >= 0; i--) {
                $('.rate-btn-'+i).addClass('rate-btn-active');
            };
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "zalian/rating_ajax.php",
                data: dataRate,
                success:function(){}
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Links to external sites can be useful at first. But if they become deprecated in time. The question no longer becomes of any use to any other user on SO.

Comment: Display a message , certainly tooltip which says double click to rate as half, then just redesign your code and add a half filled star as background image

Comment: there's already a fiddle on how my code works @Zealander

Comment: @Kev What Jay basically meant was that you should also include your html and css. To lead in the direction of solving your problem: At the moment you have 5 steps, just double it and display 2 steps as 1 full star. Styling shouldnt be much of a problem

Comment: As AlexG suggest, you'd have to split each star into 2 buttons the right side of the star would be half star and left side is full star - 10 buttons in total

Comment: You should check this out, I am not if this will help you tho. http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh

Answer (score 1):

I came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qody1ckz/5/).

Basically using fontAwesome instead of pictures and calculating the # of stars based on the star index so you don't need that many classes.

```
$('.rank-half').hover(function() {
    var thisIndex = $(this).index(),
        parent = $(this).parent(),
        parentIndex = parent.index(),
        ranks = $('.rank-container');
    for (var i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
        if(i < parentIndex) {
            $(ranks[i]).removeClass('half').addClass('full');
        } else {
            $(ranks[i]).removeClass('half').removeClass('full');
        }
    }
    if(thisIndex == 0) {
        parent.addClass('half');
    } else {
        parent.addClass('full');
    }
});
```